# Deeplearning4J slow on Word2Vec

Tags: performance, word2vec, nd4j

I want to try word2vec with this configuration:

```
compile "org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:1.0.0-beta2"
compile "org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:1.0.0-beta2"
//compile "org.nd4j:nd4j-cuda-9.2-platform:1.0.0-beta2"
compile group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-nlp', version: '1.0.0-beta2'
compile group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-ui_2.11', version: '1.0.0-beta2'

    SentenceIterator iter = new BasicLineIterator(new File("E:/temp/text_1.txt"));
    TokenizerFactory t = new DefaultTokenizerFactory();

    t.setTokenPreProcessor(new CommonPreprocessor());

    Word2Vec vec = new Word2Vec.Builder()
            .minWordFrequency(20)
            .iterations(1)
            .layerSize(150)
            .seed(42)
            .windowSize(5)
            .iterate(iter)
            .tokenizerFactory(t)
            .allowParallelTokenization(true)
            .batchSize(1000)
            .workers(8)
            .elementsLearningAlgorithm(new SkipGram<>())
            .build();
    vec.fit();
```

The file with the sentences is about 15GB and has one sentence per line.

```
22:33:07.116 [main] INFO  o.d.m.w.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Sequences checked: [200000]; Current vocabulary size: [48699]; Sequences/sec: 8298,07; Words/sec: 69217,82;
```

How can I tune it so that its not so slow? It took over 24 hours to just build the vocab.

These are some lines from the textfile I want to process:

jeden abend sieht sie den schatten am fenster

dann weht ein eisiger hauch ins zimmer

der unheimliche besucher laesst sich nicht abwehren

bei seinem anblick erstarrt die frau vor entsetzen

denn sie kann nicht begreifen dass ploetzlich der mann vor ihr steht den sie vor vielen jahren begraben hat

dem unheimlichen besucher eine falle zu stellen

Comment: How big is your text file? How are you doing the sentences? Bad input data can slow things down quite a bit if you're doing it wrong. It's kinda hard to tell with the little information you've given here.

Comment: Hello, as I mentioned above, the textfile is about 15GB. What do you mean how I do the sentences? There is one sentence per line and I tried different Sentenceiterators (in the listing above the BasicLineIterator).

Comment: Ahh sorry I missed that. I'm guessing it's just plain OOM then. How are you trying to run it? Can you get rid of the batch size and worker configuration and see what that does?

Comment: Got rid of it, same performance... I also tried to start it with additional parameters: -Xmx6g -Xms2g -Dorg.bytedeco.javacpp.maxbytes=8G -Dorg.bytedeco.javacpp.maxphysicalbytes=16G but nothing changed

Comment: What kind of hardware are you running on? The disk can matter quite a bit as well.

Comment: Can you also please add which DL4J version you are using?

Comment: I use an Intel i7 2600K with 24GB ram, I also tried used a ram-disk, same performance... the dl4j-version is 1.0.0-beta2

Comment: Could you file an issue with a way of us reproducing this? We'll need to dive in to your setup a bit. There's definitely something wrong here. I'm not sure if it's your input data or what.

Comment: I added some information to the question, what else do you need?